# How to get emoji shortcut bar above keyboard like Instagram?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, emoji

I am creating a comment section in my app and I would like to add the shortcut emoji bar like done in Instagram. This is the feature I am talking about :

[image]

Is this a given feature in android? or we get a list of latest used emojis and then we create a custom layout and show the list? anyway how do we achieve this? I tried to look for it many places but it only shows how to enable emoji on the given keyboard which already is enabled for me.

Answer (score 1):

Instagram doesn't show the whole emojis above `EditText` they show specific emojis, So can use a `TextView` or `ImageView`, that when users click on it, it will add emoji to you edit text.

Here is the [emoji list](https://emojipedia.org/google/) and you can use it to make a layout like Instagram.

Comment: Instagram shows the latest used emojis. How do I get that list?

Comment: @ParthAnjaria for that you need to manage a local record of last used emojies

Answer (score 0):

Add a layout above `EditText` with Emojis you want and add them to `EditText` when clicked.

Comment: Instagram shows the latest used emojis. How do I get that list?